# How to save parent NSManangedObjectContext from child queue?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following setup:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *parent = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
                            initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
// other setup for parent

NSManagedObjectContext *child = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
                          initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[child setParentContext:parent];
```

What I want is to save the parent whenever the child saves, so currently I do something like this:

```
[child performBlock^{
      [child save:nil];
      [parent performBlock:^{
          [parent save:nil];
      }
}];
```

That's me being safe, and calling save within the context's own queue. Is that necessary? Could I just do:

```
[child performBlock^{
     [child save:nil];
     [parent save:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the second variant. You would execute the `save` operation for the parent context on the queue that is associated with the child context, instead of the main queue.

This means that the `save` operation would be executed on a (potentially) different thread than the main thread, which is not allowed because managed object contexts are not thread safe.

See also [Concurrency Support for Managed Object Contexts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)
in the *Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0*:

> You use contexts using the queue-based concurrency types in
>   conjunction with two new methods: `performBlock:` and
>   `performBlockAndWait:`. ... The one exception is: if your code is
>   executing on the main thread, you can invoke methods on the main queue
>   style contexts directly instead of using the block based API.
>
> `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` ensure the block operations
>   are executed on the queue specified for the context. ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the main context to save on its own queue and I assume that you use main queue for the parent context so you could do it like;

```
[child performBlock^{
     [child save:nil];
     [parent performSelectorOnMainThread:@selectorr(save:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}];
```

This code will make sure that your parent managedObjectContxt will always save in the main thread. And I think that it is a good idea to have main context always on the main thread which makes it easy to synchronise between different threads.